# Rails 3 application templates, how to also template brands and layouts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to build my own template for use for anytime our coders want to create a new app for our companies ecosystem.  I used a hodgepodge of information from here:

http://everydayrails.com/2011/02/28/rails-3-application-templates.html

and

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html

And seemed to of created a nice template file that I am still tinkering on but should be setting up a database, devise, and a few other gems (and throwing it into git automatically).  Its ran with this command:

```
rails new ournewapp -m ourbrand.rb
```

So it uses whats in that .rb file to set up the right gems, the database push to git rake install etc.  I just am not sure if this is the right approach and how to extend this to automatically copy over branding such as: logos, css, layouts utilizing both etc.

Ideally a run of this would be something like:

```
%> rails new OurCompanysNewApp
'Would you like to use active directory? Yes
'Would you like to add in Companies Branding? Yes
' WOuld you like to use twitter boot strap?  No
' WOuld you like... etc. etc.
' Add this to github?  yes
' Set up standard capistrano? yes
   creating your app!!!!
create  README.rdoc
create  Rakefile
create  config.ru
create  .gitignore
create  Gemfile
create  app
create  app/assets/images/rails.png
create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
create  app/models/.gitkeep
create  config
create  config/routes.rb
```

So is this `Application Template` the way to go or are there other more preferred ways to do the above (build an app with stuff depending upon if the user chooses it at creation time AND if the branding question is answered, copy over the appropriate layout/css/html.erb files to support that)?  If this is the preferred method, then I am close just not sure how to do the layout/css/hmlt.erb for branding setup.

Answer (score 0):

`Rails Application Templates` are the right way to go for your given problem.

You might want to have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/templates.html for customized controller and model templates. A `Rails Application Template` is good start for a new application but in that application you'll want to have customized model and controller templates to save time in the development process.

Comment: and the Rails Application templates are the way to go with getting the right look and feel of an app set up out o fthe box? I guess I am confused as to where that comes from.  The idea is all the developers can build their own apps but use that as a base, so they all need the base template (and look feel code css etc) on their machine before they could use our code shops application templates?

Comment: `Rails Application Templates` are perfect to setup you preferred environment. Customized controller and model templates are good to safe time during the development. But: If you haven't missed it yet you don't need it.

Comment: okay so Rails Application templates it is, I will research this how to get it to set up the environment... and set up the look and feel (or am i miss reading, look and feel comes from a customized controller and model templates?

Comment: Look and feel doesn't come from customized controller or models.

Comment: didn't think that sounded right.  So again then setting up look and feel comes from Rails Application Templates? I am confused by its a css file, its layout code, does every dev need that on their box so it can be "Copied" into the proper folders during the new app creation?

Comment: IMO you should think about just using the standard rails components and customize them after you feel the need for customizing. Don't do the seconds step before the first one. Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/asset_pipeline.html about the CSS and other assets.